# Oembed For Instagram Jquery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Need a bit help, i want to embed Instagram into my website but i can only use Jquery or JavaScript as my platform doesn't support PHP.

I Also tried few things but it doesn't seems to work.

https://github.com/starfishmod/jquery-oembed-all

Looking forward to your replies.

Answer (score -1):

Check this one out: http://web.stagram.com/tools/#blog_parts, creates a "widget" for your page!

Comment: Thats Iframe, I asked from oEmbed? Or anything else and it is taking me to http://web.stagram.com not to my instagram profile

Comment: Well it helps you do the oEmbed-thingy. Web.stagram.com is Instagram, but the one that was showing it on the web before instagram did.

Comment: Still, thats not what i was looking for :/

Comment: Sorry cant help you then! :(